# Why install nodejs and npm for Angualr2 to work with Grails 3.0

Tags: angular, grails, typescript

i am trying to run a simple Angular 2 application using Grails 3.0.9 as the server side. What i dont understand is that it is required to have nodejs. I am aware that Node.js is a server side technology like grails. So why is it necessary to install Node.js and its modules. I read somewhere that node.js comes with a package that translates TypeScript to JavaScript and hence this installation is mandatory . Not sure how correct this is and if it is this case cant i use some other tool to convert TypeScript to JavaScript in Grails 3.0 ...

Answer (score 0):

As it is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37267993/5924315)

Node.js and NPM are not needed but it does ease tasks such as compiling the Typescript code etc. You don't however need to create a Node.js server to run an Angular2 application, for example if you are using Firebase as backend your client application will communicate directly with Firebase using the Angularfire2 module.

I would recommend that you look at [Angular CLI](http://cli.angular.io) which will create the framework for your Angular2 application.

**Edit:**

Ok, I somewhat misunderstood you question. Since Grail is a "is a full stack framework and attempts to solve as many pieces of the web development puzzle" the [Angular2 profile](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/webServices.html#angular2Profile) in in Grails is configured with both an Angular2 client and a Node.js server side application. In other words you need to install both Angular2 and Node.js to get this **full stack framework** to work.

Comment: I understand that node.js and npm is required to compile the TypeScript to javascript and yes you are correct that to run Angular 2 applications we dont need node.js. only the Angular CLI will do.  But when i visited the grails 3.2.* documentation it said Node.js and NPM as a prerequisite to use the angular 2 profile available in Grails 3.2.* . This is the part that i dont understand as why we need node.js and npm when i am using Grails as the server side technology.

Comment: @Apoorv You don't need node and npm to run Grails, however you need it to build the client side application

Comment: @Oyvind Fredstie You don't need to install anything to get Grails to work (other than Java). If you create an application with the default profile it comes with GSP support and scaffolding for the client side.

Comment: @JamesKleeh I understand that we dont need to install anything else apart from java to run grails .... But if i want to use Angular2 as the client side framework the grails documentation says to install node and npm and Angular 2 CLI .... this is the part i do not understand

Comment: @Apoorv Because it is necessary to build the client side application. You don't need it in production because it is already built. I would advise you to join the Grails slack to answer questions like these

Comment: Thanks James for your answer ... Sure will join the Grails Stack and will post my queries there