# Why there is a dependency to install NodeJs for a .Net core web application which uses angular template?

Tags: c#, node.js, angular, asp.net-core, dependencies

When I create a new .NET core web application in visual studio using angular template and try to run the barebone application, build error is thrown asking to install nodeJs. After studying that angular is totally a different package from NodeJs, why is this project has dependency on nodejs installation ?

Problem solved after installing nodejs, but not sure why nodejs is a dependency here.

FYI, I am relatively new to angular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we have install Node.js for Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267510/why-do-we-have-install-node-js-for-angular-2-0)

Comment: I believe that is to install packages via NPM which stands for node package manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Typescript used by angular cant be understood by browers, so you need to transpile the code to javascript for make them work. The typescript transpiler for converting typescript to javascript requires nodejs.
- NPM package mangager which helps in managing your project dependencies comes by default with nodejs

Answer (score 3):

As Ameer Pappay mentioned, NodeJs is needed to [transpile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) typescript into javascript and for other development tools that you might need while you develop your application. But once you create a distribution build, it can be served through any web server and will not require a NodeJs instance.