# Why we have to install NodeJS for ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm a beginner in ReactJS also for NodeJS. I would love to know why we have to install NodeJS run ReactJS application as ReactJS is client-side scripting.

Comment: Indeed you need `npm` for package management in React. And `npm` generally requires NodeJs. If you can find a way to install it on its own, you would not explicitly need NodeJs.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398537/do-i-need-node-js-to-use-angularjs#40770429 .

Comment: check out this medium article [link](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/modern-javascript-explained-for-dinosaurs-f695e9747b70), it has 71k claps, you may find valuable insights into this in more detail

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answer is incorrect. 
**You don't NEED Node.js**, in fact you could create a project without running a single `npm` command. [Just follow this guide.](https://shinglyu.github.io/web/2016/04/06/minimal_react.html)

The main reason, as pointed out in the article, is:

1. Easy package management. This means you can upgrade the package easily later on
2. JSX is the templating language that makes it way easier to write components: `<h1>Hello Word</h1>` reads so much better than `React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello World')`
3. Managing module imports, as opposed to having global variables around everywhere, it's great to have encapsulation and import modules as needed.
4. Build step and workflow. For a modern project, you will need tools to minify your code, cache busting, transpiling (writing pure javascript for old browser is a pain and you really shouldn't do it manually), the list goes on and on.

Comment: Okay, it's not `technically` mandatory, but why shouldn't you use a package manager to manage dependencies? It totally makes no sense

Comment: I'm heavily reliant on node, but I can see how small projects could benefit from using just a few lines of script tag to pull libraries from CDN as opposed to a full on project

Comment: Even in small applications dependencies are hardly less than a couple, using a standard to define and manage them universally can always be convenient for many reasons. But of course this can be only an opinion, and of course you can also simply link them from a CDN

Comment: @JonnyLin, thank you so much for explanation on query. marking it as accepted answer. Hope to see you next time.

Answer (score 4):

Because almost all the JavaScript libraries/frameworks are using the Node Package Manager (NPM), that makes much more convenient to manage JavaScript dependencies in general, both client-side and server-side.

Edit: It's not really `technically` necessary, but using a package manager is the best practice for managing dependencies and sub-dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you don't have to. When you are in the development step, you can install it for package management. Only webpack is needed to bundle, compile, transpile the code.